# How to aggregate results to list in wso2dss

Tags: wso2, wso2-data-services-server

Assumig i call service in wso2dss that executed a query which return next result:

```
PERSON_ID | DOCUMENT_ID
    1            10
    1            11
    2            12
    2            13
```

I want to pack documents for every person to list and then retunt it in next format about.

```
<results>
    <person>
        <id>1</id>
        <documents>
            <document>10</document>
            <document>11</document>
        </documents>
    </person>

    <person>
        <id>2</id>
        <documents>
            <document>12</document>
            <document>13</document>
        </documents>
    </person>
</results>
```

How can i group documents?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use XSLT transformation on the query to get the result formatted. A sample can be found from [here](https://docs.wso2.com/display/DSS350/XSLT+Transformation+Sample).

Thanks